# SQL Server 2016 with R Services in the cloud

Tags: sql-server, r, sql-server-2016, cloud-hosting, microsoft-r

I have developed a stored procedure that computes the best fitted curve that describes some data. In order to do that I am running a piece of R code through SQL Server using the nonlinear least squares function of R language (in case of interest the function is [nls()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/nls.html)). I have also developed a user interface to visualize these data. I am using SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition(which has R Services installed) locally in my computer.

So, now is the time to publish this implementation and I can't find any hosting solution that supports SQL Server with R-Services.

**Any suggestions on that or any alternative solutions please?**

Answer (score 2):

you can deploy the model using Operationalization in MRS 9.0.1. You can configure a web node and compute node on a separate machine to act as HTTP REST end point and execute on R codes.

You can read more in the following links:-
https://msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft-r/operationalize/about, 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/operationalize/configuration-initial

Thanks,
Shau Phang
Microsoft R Server Engineering